# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, ezswipecontroller

I am not able to compile my project.  It returns a `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64`, followed by `linker command failed with exit code 1`.

It always seems to fall under EZSwipeController cocoa pod in the logs.  What is going on?

Log:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.stackNavBars.getter : [__ObjC.UINavigationBar]", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.stackNavBars.materializeForSet : [__ObjC.UINavigationBar]", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.stackVC.getter : [__ObjC.UIViewController]!", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.stackVC.setter : [__ObjC.UIViewController]!", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.stackPageVC.getter : [__ObjC.UIViewController]!", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.stackPageVC.setter : [__ObjC.UIViewController]!", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.stackPageVC.materializeForSet : [__ObjC.UIViewController]!", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.bottomNavigationHeight.getter : CoreGraphics.CGFloat", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.titleButton.getter : __ObjC.UIButton?", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.bottomNavigationHeight.setter : CoreGraphics.CGFloat", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.stackNavBars.setter : [__ObjC.UINavigationBar]", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.titleButton.materializeForSet : __ObjC.UIButton?", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.bottomNavigationHeight.materializeForSet : CoreGraphics.CGFloat", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.pageViewController.getter : __ObjC.UIPageViewController!", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.stackStartLocation.materializeForSet : Swift.Int!", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.pageViewController.setter : __ObjC.UIPageViewController!", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.pageViewController.materializeForSet : __ObjC.UIPageViewController!", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.titleButton.setter : __ObjC.UIButton?", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.stackStartLocation.setter : Swift.Int!", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.currentStackVC.setter : __ObjC.UIViewController!", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.currentStackVC.materializeForSet : __ObjC.UIViewController!", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.stackVC.materializeForSet : [__ObjC.UIViewController]!", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.datasource.getter : weak EZSwipeController.EZSwipeControllerDataSource?", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.navigationBarShouldBeOnBottom.materializeForSet : Swift.Bool", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.datasource.setter : weak EZSwipeController.EZSwipeControllerDataSource?", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.navigationBarShouldBeOnBottom.setter : Swift.Bool", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.datasource.materializeForSet : weak EZSwipeController.EZSwipeControllerDataSource?", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.cancelStandardButtonEvents.setter : Swift.Bool", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.stackStartLocation.getter : Swift.Int!", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.navigationBarShouldBeOnBottom.getter : Swift.Bool", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.navigationBarShouldNotExist.getter : Swift.Bool", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.cancelStandardButtonEvents.materializeForSet : Swift.Bool", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.currentStackVC.getter : __ObjC.UIViewController!", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.navigationBarShouldNotExist.setter : Swift.Bool", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.cancelStandardButtonEvents.getter : Swift.Bool", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
  "EZSwipeController.EZSwipeController.navigationBarShouldNotExist.materializeForSet : Swift.Bool", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp15TaskViewSwipeVC in TaskViewSwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp7SwipeVC in SwipeVC.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7ClickUp10BoxSwipeVC in BoxSwipeVC.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/greenhouse/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClickUp-femixwixrwqyxugbrvrqmcaqvdkh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ClickUp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ClickUp.build/Release-iphoneos/ClickUp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ClickUp normal arm64
(1 failure)
```

PodFile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'ClickUp' do
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'KeychainAccess', '~> 3.0.0'
  pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.2'
  pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 3.0'
  pod "HockeySDK", '~> 4.0.2'
  pod 'SnapKit', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'HMSegmentedControl', '~> 1.5.3'
  pod 'libPhoneNumber-iOS', '~> 0.8.16'
  pod 'DateTools', '~> 1.7.0'
  pod 'RSKImageCropper', '~> 1.5.1'
  pod 'FLAnimatedImage', '~> 1.0'
  pod 'EZSwipeController', '~> 0.6.1'
  pod 'MGSwipeTableCell', '~> 1.5.5'
end
```

Comment: In your workspace are you sure that it's linked under `Build Phases` > `Link Binary with Libraries`?

Comment: In my `Build Phases` > `Link Binary with Libraries`, I have "Pods_ClickUp.framework" (ClickUp is the name of my app).  Should I be including something else?

Comment: No that's correct. I presume you've already cleaned the project, and tried pod install, and pod update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out EZSwipeController did something (commit 7 days ago), which broke the app if you are using CocoaPods.  Simply remove the cocoapod and manually drag and drop the library into the project.

Comment: I faced the same issue for WDSideMenu using CocoaPods.
Then I deleted the Pod entry and added WDSideMenu by manually drag & drop into the project.
It worked! Thanks for this solution.